# How to get the subdirectory of a ftp weblink?

Tags: files-and-directories, web-access

For example, I can use

```
FileNames["*",dir]
```

to get all subdirectory under dir if dir is some directory of my local computer. Suppose that I want to get all subdirectory of a ftp on internet, what should I do? For certain ftp link, I can use URLFetch[dir] then take some string analyz trick to get the directory like below,

```
s=URLFetch["ftp://cdaweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/data/polar/efi/efi_6secedsc/2002/"];
StringSplit[# <> ".cdf", " "][[-1]] & /@ StringSplit[s, ".cdf"]
```

but is there any method for general ftp link?